# Rewrite this line in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I've got such a class and delegate in C#:

```
public delegate void Super();
public class Event
{
    public event Super activate ;
    public void act()
    {
       if (activate != null) 
           activate();
    }
}
```

I need to rewrite it in C++/CLI. But I've got an error - `usage requires Event::activate to be data member`

```
public delegate void Super();
public ref class Event
{
    public:
        event Super ^activate;
        void act()
        {
            if (activate!=nullptr) 
                activate();
        }
};
```

Is it problem in `activate()` call?

Comment: it is unhappy because `if (activate!=nullptr)` specifically is the `activate` is not a data value

Comment: so how to do the same thing in c++/cli as in c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, in C++/CLI you don't need the null test, the compiler will insert it for you.  Just call

```
activate();
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b612y2s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) confirms this:

> The following code example demonstrates the logic used to generate the raise method of a trivial event: If the event has one or more subscribers, calling the `raise` method implicitly or explicitly calls the delegate. If the delegate's return type is not `void` and if there are zero event subscribers, the `raise` method returns the default value for the delegate type. **If there are no event subscribers, calling the `raise` method simply returns and no exception is raised.** If the delegate return type is not `void`, the delegate type is returned.

This is a very good thing, because C# encourages a race condition (the code you posted has one).  The C++/CLI compiler won't re-read the backing field between the null check and invocation, so it is thread-safe without additional effort.  The correct C# version, which is equivalent to what the C++/CLI compiler generates, is:

```
var activate_copy = activate;
if (activate_copy != null) 
    activate_copy();
```